# Apple Push Notifications + TestFlight + Enterprise wildcard provisioning profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I work in an organization which have an Apple enterprise provisioning profile.
We are developing an iOS application that makes use of Apple Push Notifications, and would like to use TestFlight to distribute it to many users in the organizations without having to register their device ids in TestFlight.

Can we use an enterprise **wildcard** provisioning profile to distribute via TestFlight an application that uses Apple Push Notifications?

Or can we use an explicit provisioning profile to distribute the app via TestFlight without having to register those employees devices in TestFlight beforehand?

Thanks in advance,
Ido

Comment: I don't think you can use any wildcard profile for push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It should work!

> What about Enterprise Apps?
>   If you are registered with Apple's Enterprise Program and are making Enterprise Apps, no worries...TestFlight works with those too. TestFlight fully supports Enterprise Apps and it works much like Ad Hoc apps for distribution. Just upload an Enterprise signed app and distribute to your team and only approved members of your team will have access to the application for installation.

Source: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq

Comment: TestFlight works, yes, but wildcards and push, which he asks about in his question, do not. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Enterprise Distribution profile, there is no need to use testflight any more. You can just put it anywhere on the internet and let users download it.

Registering devices is needed only for development profiles. There are no distribution wildcard profiles.